# Changing the color of text within the "content" CSS property

Tags: css

I have a form with a bunch of required fields set up as following:

```
<div class="required">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text">
</div>

<style>
    .required:after { content:" *"; }
</style>
```

Now I would like to make that asterisk a polite red, indicating that perhaps something went wrong with the filling out of the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the color property: `.required:after { content:" *"; color: red; }`

Style properties will have effect on the content just as well.

Comment: I feel like such a noob, but then again CSS was never my forte.  Never.  I thought I would have to do a bunch of div stacking nonsense, inheriting some properties from one onto the next and etc...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good example : [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/xpZST/1/)

Having : `.required:after { content: "*"; color: red; }`